# CSS3 effect not Working

Tags: html, css

I created a site. and I call a image from `DIV CSS`

```
.header_bottom_area {
  background: url(../img/HomepagePanels.jpg)no-repeat scroll center center;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: 911px;
}
```

And I want this image that same [link](http://postimg.org/image/4937ifn9n/) It is Possible from CSS? Thanks

Comment: Could you please explain your what you are trying to do and post any relevant code and not just link an image. "CSS3 effect not Working" ... what css3 effect?

Comment: Go to link and see that. I want same design for my image. And i try css but i cant it. Just I want to image bottom fold style. Please see this [link](http://postimg.org/image/4937ifn9n/)

Comment: You need to post any relevant CSS and HTML for your header

Comment: sorry i can't understand.

Comment: You need to post your code in your question (HTML and CSS code)

Comment: And do you inform that?

Comment: Click the edit button below you question and add your code to your question then save it, thats all I'm asking

Comment: You could use `clip-path:polygon()`, it's not supported in IE but could still be interesting http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path

Answer (score 0):

The following CSS should get you started (where .sample-box is a class applied to the image or it's containing DIV):

```
.sample-box
{
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px;
}

.sample-box::before 
{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-top: 150px; /* same as height of this ::before item */
    margin-left: 0px; /* (padding * -1) of main element */
    content: "";
    border-width: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-left-width: 400px; /* (width + padding) of main element */
    border-bottom-width: 50px; /* height of "mask" */
    border-bottom-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0); /* color of "mask" */
}

.sample-box::after 
{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    margin-top: 132px; /* adjust to make it work for you */
    margin-left: 0px; /* position ::after item horizontally */
    content: "";
    border-width: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-right-width: 400px; /* (width + padding) of main element */
    border-bottom-width: 50px; /* height of "mask" */
    border-bottom-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0); /* color of "mask" */
}
```